# Reading XML with namespace and repeating nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<resource>
  <description>TTT</description>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <entity xmlns="TdmBLRuPlUz.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="TdmBLRuPlUz.xsd TdmBLRuPlUz.xsd">
    <UzdProd>
      <row>
        <F_DAUDZ>50</F_DAUDZ>
        <BR_DAUDZ/>
        <DAUDZ>50</DAUDZ>
        <U_DAUDZ/>
        <NKODS>ST2.0_014_023</NKODS>
      </row>
    </UzdProd>
    <UzdMat>
      <row>
        <NKODS>SAG 2.0_014_150</NKODS>
        <NNOSAUK>Sagatave 2.0mm*0.14*150m</NNOSAUK>
        <PK_VIEN>1</PK_VIEN>
        <DAUDZ>0.077</DAUDZ>
        <F_DAUDZ>0.077</F_DAUDZ>
      </row>
    </UzdMat>
  </entity>
</resource>
```

And this is my C# code:

```
XNamespace ns = "TdmBLRuPlUz.xsd";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants(ns + "row"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Element(ns + "NKODS").Value);
    string NKODS = element.Element(ns + "NKODS").Value;
    string F_DAUDZ = element.Element(ns + "F_DAUDZ").Value;
    string DAUDZ = element.Element(ns + "DAUDZ").Value;
}
```

What I need is to read values from the XML nodes `NKODS`, `F_DAUDZ` and `DAUDZ`.

The problem is that there are repeating nodes with those names and with this code it gives me the last ones which are under `UzdMat` node. What would be the way to get the values for these nodes under `UzdProd`?
I tried to change `row` to `UzdProd`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Could you please split your XML and C# sample for sake of clarity

Comment: (From Review:) I added the relevant tag `C#` to your question and formatted your code sections.

Comment: Your loop should run twice - once for the first row, once for the second. Do you only want the values for the row inside `UzdProd`?

Comment: Later I will need to get values from both UzdProd and UzdMat

Comment: Your code (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uCNMtA)) gets both already. What do you actually want the output of this to be?

Comment: I want it to save NKODS values from UzdProd in string NKODS. And for example NKODS values from UzdMat to string Mat_NKODS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the specific row you want rather than looping through all of them. For example:

```
var prodRow = doc.Descendants(ns + "UzdProd").Elements(ns + "row").Single();
var matRow = doc.Descendants(ns + "UzdMat").Elements(ns + "row").Single();

var prodNkods = (string) prodRow.Element(ns + "NKODS");
var matNkods = (string) matRow.Element(ns + "NKODS");
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tIGZPr) for a working demo.

Comment: This works. Thanks. But what if for example UzdProd row would contain another node that would have another row with NKODS? I guess it would throw me exception because of Single()? Just thinking ahead.

Comment: @WhizBoy `Elements` only finds immediate children (wheras `Descendants` is recursive). In the case you suggest, this query would still work as the `UzdProd` row would still only have a single `NKODS` child element.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement entity = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "entity").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = entity.GetDefaultNamespace();

            var results = entity.Elements().Select(x => new {
                uzd = x.Name.LocalName,
                dict = x.Descendants(ns + "row").Elements().GroupBy(y => y.Name.LocalName, z => (string)z)
                   .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z.FirstOrDefault())
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I only got node names when I tried to print that list. How can I get values from that list in those variables I have?

Comment: It is a dictionary with keys and values.  Not all elements had value so you will get some empty values.  To get values from dict either enumerate through the dictionary or get values from keys.